# Which type of function fits more

Tags: c, coding-style

Say, I need to sort some scores from `classOne`, `classTwo`, and `classThree`. Each `class` has their own file, named as stated previously. I need to print them on the screen, as following:

```
Class One:
John 23
Timmy 34
Drake 35

Class Two:
Tina 25
Bob 31

Class Three:
Anthony 18
Rose 20
```

In the files themselves, each data is formatted in `name#score`, therefore I used `fscanf` to read them properly and print them as `name score`.

Now, coming to the sorting part. I propose two methods:

1. Sort every file respectively in 1 function
2. Sort each file in their own function

According to Robert C. Martin in his book, *Clean Code*, one of the main rules about functions is that they should do only ONE thing. This means that Number Two obviously stands, however, I think that it is WET and Number One could do the same with a much DRYer approach.

Below are some code snippets.

Number 1:

```
void sortFile(){
    FILE *classScore;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        char name [50][20]; //assuming there are 50 students
        int score [50];
        if (i == 0){
            classScore = fopen ("score1.txt", "r");
        }
        else if (i == 1){
            classScore = fopen ("score2.txt", "r");
        }
        else if (i == 2){
            classScore = fopen ("score3.txt", "r");
        }
        //stores file content into array
        fclose (classScore);
        //sort mechanism (bubble sort)
        //print sorted array content
    }
}
```

Number 2:

```
void sortClassOne(){
    FILE *classScore;
    char name [50][20]; //assuming there are 50 students
    int score [50];
    classScore = fopen ("score1.txt", "r");
    //stores file content into array
    fclose (classScore);
    //sort mechanism (bubble sort)
    //print sorted array content
    }

void sortClassTwo(){
    FILE *classScore;
    char name [50][20]; //assuming there are 50 students
    int score [50];
    classScore = fopen ("score2.txt", "r");
    //stores file content into array
    fclose (classScore);
    //sort mechanism (bubble sort)
    //print sorted array content
    }

void sortClassThree(){
    FILE *classScore;
    char name [50][20]; //assuming there are 50 students
    int score [50];
    classScore = fopen ("score3.txt", "r");
    //stores file content into array
    fclose (classScore);
    //sort mechanism (bubble sort)
    //print sorted array content
    }
```

With this, which between both methods would fit (at least in my case)? I understand that I am not working with a really big project or somekind, but I would like to get myself used to good habits in writing codes further on.

Thank you! ;)

Comment: I choose option (3) : `void sortClassFile(const char *fname)`

Comment: If all files are to be processed exactly the same way, pass the filename as an argument to a single function which does the reading and processing. And split the reading and processing into their own functions. I'm a strong believer in the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) principles.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Do I get it right that your method would be 2 functions with each having 3 calls?

Comment: Four functions actually: One `read_sort_and_print` function which opens the file (path passed as an argument), and is the function you call. Then that function in turn calls `read_data` to read the actual data, calls `sort_data` to sort the newly read data, and `print_data` which prints the newly sorted data.

Comment: By the way, if all the files are named in the form of `scoreX.txt` where `X` is a number from `1` to `3`, then I'd also use a loop from `1` to `3` (inclusive) which uses `snprintf` to construct the file-name and then calls the `read_sort_and_print` function.

Comment: Ahh, I see I see. Thank you so much to both of you :)

Comment: Also, I notice that you (@Someprogrammerdude) have been around answering my questions. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my working code here! I followed some suggestions from the comments.

```
void readFile(FILE *fileOpenedToRead){
char buffer[20];
int temp;
j = 0;
while (fscanf (fileOpenedToRead, "%[^#]#%d\n", buffer, &temp) != EOF){
    strcpy (namePlayer[j], buffer);
    score[j] = temp;
    j++;
}
fclose (fileOpenedToRead);}

void sortFile(){
int store;
char storage[20];
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < j - i - 1; k++){
        if (score[k] > score[k+1]){
            store = score[k]; //swap score
            score[k] = score[k+1];
            score[k+1] = store;
            strcpy (storage, namePlayer[k]); //swap name
            strcpy (namePlayer[k], namePlayer[k+1]);
            strcpy (namePlayer[k+1], storage);
        }
    }
}}

void displayFile(){
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
    printf ("| %d", i+1);
    if (i < 9) printf ("   ");
    else printf ("   ");
    printf ("| %s", namePlayer[i]);
    for (int k = 0; k < 51 - strlen(namePlayer[i]); k++) printf (" ");
    printf ("|    %d |\n", score[i]);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I would personally prefer the first option as it would be as you mentioned "DRYer". But I would have some slight modifications to the codes.
Firstly, I would add a numOfClass parameter to dynamically determine if there is how many classes. Secondly, assume all of the file have the same format of name `scoreX.txt`, I would create a string for the file name and I dont need the `if else` block.

```cs
void sortFile(int numOfClass){
    FILE *classScore;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfClass; i++){
        char name [50][20]; //assuming there are 50 students
        int score [50];
        string className = "score" + (i + 1) + ".txt";
        classScore = fopen(className, "r");
        //stores file content into array
        fclose (classScore);
        //sort mechanism (bubble sort)
        //print sorted array content
    }
}
```

Comment: The expression `"score" + (i + 1) + ".txt"` will not work very well. Neither will the type `string`.

Comment: my bad, i did not notice that it was in C not C#